# What is a d-prime experiment

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, signal-processing, neuroscience

I am reading about [Roc curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)  and have encountered the term ""D-prime experiment" does anyone know what it is?

Comment: http://www.mbfys.ru.nl/~robvdw/DGCN22/PRACTICUM_2011/LABS_2011/ALTERNATIVE_LABS/Lesson_8.html#8

Answer (score 0):

d prime is a term used in signal detection theory, which is related to ROC curves and so on. Conceptually, it measures how separable two distributions are. In the particularly case of signal detection theory, the two distributions are the noise distribution and the signal+noise distribution. The larger d prime is, the more separable the two distributions are, and the better the detection performance can be.

In the context of cognitive sciences, d prime is often used in psychophysics. A d prime experiment is one where the d prime is estimated experimentally. Note that in a given task where the physical stimulus can be described by one variable (say, in the detection of a barely audible beep, sound intensity is the said variable), d prime is dependently on the stimulus variable. Therefore, d prime is not estimated by varying the stimulus variable; in the most basic paradigm of d prime estimation (which incidentally can also be used to estimate ROC curves), subjects are asked to make binary forced choices about whether they detect the stimulus or not (two-alternative forced choice, or 2AFC) with varying confidence levels (e.g. "say you detect the sound only when you are absolutely sure" vs. "even when you are not so sure").

Wikipedia has a nice page with a formal definition (link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_index). Note that as is common in signal detection theory, the distributions are assumed to be Gaussian. If you were trying to tell the "separability" of two non-Gaussian distributions, Kullback-Leibler divergence is a more solid way.